# Changing command prompt directory from Node.js script

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to change the directory of terminal using with Node.js program but not able to achieve it. Script is run as `node app.js dir_name` so first I'm creating the directory and then trying to change into that directory using cd command. Directory is created but the directory for terminal is not changed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var platform = process.platform; 
var figlet = require('figlet');
var chalk = require('chalk');

if(process.argv.length < 3){
    console.log(
       chalk.green(
          figlet.textSync('mdcd', { horizontalLayout: 'full' })
                  )
               );
    console.log(chalk.red("Please provide a directory name"));
  }else{

    if(platform.includes("win")){
      //console.log("Its Windows");
    }else {  

            var exec = require('child_process').exec;
            var command_1 = "mkdir "+process.argv[2];
            var command_2 = "cd "+process.cwd()+"/"+process.argv[2];
            exec(command_1, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
              if(error){
                console.log("Something bad happened"+error);
              }else {               
                 exec(command_2, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                     if(error){
                        console.log("Something bad happened"+error);
                     }
                 });
              }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> command prompt directory from Node.js script

You cannot change the `command prompt` directory. Basically you have the process tree:

```
cmd / term
  | -> NodeJs
```

You shouldn't change the working dir for cmd. However there are command you can execute to change the working dir of *any* process e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282009

## More

You can however change the the working dir for the `nodejs` process (which is what I suspect you want to do) using `process.chdir` https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory

Comment: I wanted to do this, run a node script from the console, that node script takes an argument and creates a directory of that name if it doesn't already exist and cd into it. So after executing $~/a/b/c> node app.js d at the terminal, the current working directory for terminal should be d.